# Watir. Select multiple radio button options

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3

The issue I'm dealing with, and unable to solve due to my ignorance, is that I have a page on a browser with different education requirements which each have four radio buttons. I want to be able to select a certain radio button for each education requirement.

The code I have is like this:

```
radios = browser.radios
radios.each do |radio|
  radio.input(:value => "very").set
end
```

However this keep giving me an error message saying: "undefined method 'set' for #Watir::Input:0x103a5d508"

I did something similar for select_lists where I changed the option of all select_lists on a page to the 2nd option which worked:

```
lists = browser.select_lists 
lists.each do |list|
  list.option(:index, 1).select
end
```

For my code for the radio buttons I tried using radio.option but it gave me a similar error: "NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #Watir::Option:0x103a466a0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The code

```
radios = browser.radios
radios.each do |radio|
  radio.input(:value => "very").set
end
```

Says that for each radio button on the page, set the first input element with value "very". This suggests that you are looking for html like:

```
<radio>
  <input value="very" />
</radio>
```

This is probably not what the html looks like.

**Solution**

I assume the html you really want to set is like:

```
<input type="radio" value="very" />
```

To set each radio button with value "very", the code should be:

```
# Get a collection of all radios with value "very"
radios = browser.radios(:value => "very")

# Iterate through each radio button in the collection and set it
radios.each do |radio|
  radio.set
end
```

This can be shortened to simply:

```
browser.radios(:value => "very").each(&:set)
```